# how to pass className to svg in styled components

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, styled-components

I have been trying to style svg icon component via styled component and facing some issue but it's not working.The style i apply to close icon are not getting applied

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Close from './close.svg'

const CloseIcon = ({ className , ...props }) => <Close {...props} className={className} />

const styledCloseIcon = styled(CloseIcon)`
  &.ui.modal {
    .modal-icon-close {
      width: 14px;
      height: 24px;
      fill: black;
      top: 12px;
      right: 14px;
    }
  }
`
export default styledCloseIcon
```

close.svg

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M13.627 12.213l9.9 9.9-1.414 1.414-9.9-9.9-9.9 9.9L.9 22.113l9.9-9.9-9.9-9.9L2.314.9l9.9 9.9 9.899-9.9 1.414 1.415-9.9 9.9z"/>
</svg>
```

This close icon is being used in semantic ui react modal
https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/modal/#variations-close-icon

```
<Modal
      size='small'
      open={true}
      closeIcon={<Close className='modal-icon-close'/>}
      closeOnDimmerClick={false}
      className={classNames(className)}
      >
```

Comment: I hope this will help: https://www.pinkdroids.com/blog/svg-react-styled-components/

Comment: yeah ,thanks. i read it already. didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

I think there are a couple of issues

1. `import Close from './close.svg';` isn't a valid react component
2. Unnest the class in the styled component

## Solution

First create a proper SVG react component

```
const CloseIcon = ({ className, ...props }) => (
  <svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
    {...props}
    className={className}
  >
    <path d="M13.627 12.213l9.9 9.9-1.414 1.414-9.9-9.9-9.9 9.9L.9 22.113l9.9-9.9-9.9-9.9L2.314.9l9.9 9.9 9.899-9.9 1.414 1.415-9.9 9.9z" />
  </svg>
);
```

Second make `modal-icon-close` a top-level class in the styled component

```
const StyledCloseIcon = styled(CloseIcon)`
  &.modal-icon-close {
    width: 14px;
    height: 24px;
    fill: black;
    top: 12px;
    right: 14px;
  }
`;
```

[image: Edit how to pass className to svg in styled-components]

What doesn't make much sense to me is why internalize the classname and CSS and then require the correct classname prop to be passed anyway?  You could simplify the component by also specifying the `className` prop using `.attrs`

```
const StyledCloseIcon = styled(CloseIcon).attrs(() => ({
  className: 'modal-icon-close',
}))`
  &.modal-icon-close {
    width: 14px;
    height: 24px;
    fill: black;
    top: 12px;
    right: 14px;
  }
`;
```

Or just simply eliminate the classname altogether

```
const StyledCloseIcon = styled(CloseIcon)`
    width: 14px;
    height: 24px;
    fill: black;
    top: 12px;
    right: 14px;
`;
```

Answer (score 3):

When you call `styled(CloseIcon)` you are already styling the `SVG` because the custom component accepts `className` prop so `styled-components` can inject the `className` and only renders the `SVG` icon.

Try omitting all the nested class names and directly apply the styles.

Here is an example,

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import styled from "styled-components";
import { ReactComponent as Close } from "./close.svg";

const CloseIcon = ({ className, ...props }) => (
  <Close {...props} className={className} />
);

const StyledCloseIcon = styled(CloseIcon)`
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  fill: #ee4845;
`;

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <StyledCloseIcon />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Working demo in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-carson-cc1fe?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: Going to be honest here, the `import { ReactComponent as Close } from "./close.svg";` is pretty slick. I've not seen that *ever* in the 3+ years I've been working with react. Do you have links to any documentation that explains this?

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/#adding-svgs

Comment: @DrewReese : you don't even have to do import { ReactComponent as Close } from "./close.svg"; you can just import the .svg as " import Close from '../close.svg' .

Answer (score 0):

here's how I assign className to SVG file:

```
import { ReactComponent as MyImage } from '../assets/img/myimage.svg' 

<MyImage
    className='myClassName'
    fill='white'                            
/>
```

Index.css:

```
.hoverColor:hover {
    fill: yellow !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Comment: this usually doesnt work